# sensor programming

Tags: programming-languages, sensors

I´ve a question according sensor programming. I´m searching a sensor that tells me, for example, if a glass of water is more than half full. I´ve already googled that, but I can´t find anything. 
So my questions are:

- Where can I buy such a sensor?
- What programming language do I need to control such a sensor?

Thanks for answers..

**Update from comments below one of the answers**

> What I really need it for is a big container, in which is some corn. I
>   want to use the sensor to tell me, just as the corn is under a defined
>   point of the container. So that I can calculate, at which time I have
>   to refill the container.

Answer (score 2):

Your sensor could be a level sensor.  There are several principles on which level sensors work ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_sensor)).  Some of them will work with granular solid material.  (For example, an ultrasonic range sensor could shoot a pulse at the surface of corn mass, detect the reflection, measure round trip time of flight.)

... or it could be a [proximity sensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_sensor), as somebody had suggested above.

... or it could be a weight sensor.  [Here's an application note on weighing vessels.](http://www.omega.com/literature/transactions/volume3/weigh.html)

If you google "level sensor for grains", you may find something useful.

What language to use would depend on what you will connect connect the sensor to.  If it will be connected to a microcontroller, the language would be C.  If it will be connected to a PC, then it would depend a lot on the particular model of the sensor.

By the way, here's a [web group dedicated to sensors](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/sensorforum).

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you could use a similar mechanism to a car's fuel tank. Have a mechanism that stays afloat in the container with an attached arm and a magnet on it, then using a Hall sensor you can observe the change in hall reading as the floating part rises or falls within the container.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the size of the glass in question? You could just get a scale and work out how heavy the glass would be when it is half full of water. My guess is that you could probably find a sensor that could do this and it would most likely need to be written in C.

This guy seems to be having the same problems:

http://forums.makezine.com/comments.php?DiscussionID=6052

Good luck.

Also check out [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) for micro controller electronics.

Comment: Ok, thanks... But the example with the glass of water was only an example.
What I really need it for is a big container, in which is some corn. 
I want to use the sensor to tell me, just as the corn is under a defined point of the container. So that I can calculate, at which time I have to refill the container. 

Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @Harald, I would say that your best plan would be to use an Infrared beam that when connected to the sensor will let you know that the container is empty to that level. 

By this I mean you have an IR beam going across the diameter of the container and a receiver at the other side. They wont be able to connect while there is corn inside but when it is empty they will connect completing your "circuit"

Answer (score 0):

"What I really need it for is a big container, in which is some corn."

Perhaps one of those sensors that are used to ensure garage entry ways are clear before an automatic garage door is allowed to close.  It uses an optical beam of light.

Comment: Yeah, I already thought about something like a light barrier. But I don´t know, if there is any way, to connect it with a PC...